# How would one write a green screen wrapper for the camera preview?

Tags: android, camera

I'm wondering if it's possible (and if so, how one would go about doing it) to write a GreenScreen wrapper for the Camera. I'm not 100% familiar with how GreenScreen works, I'm assuming since the "green" that it's detecting isn't just one shade, it has to recognize a fairly large range of hues that it replaces with the alternate image's bytes.

I realize that this is a really open ended question, but I'm just hoping that someone has done this and can point me in the right direction.

Also, how does one push the transformed image out to the camera preview?  I'm not seeing any documentation in the Camera class for how to apply a live transform to what the user sees in the "view finder".

Much obliged.